# How to do forecasting with detection of outliers in R? - Time series analysis procedure and Method

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, outliers

I have monthly time series data, and would like to do forecasting with detection of outliers .

**This is the sample of my data set:**

```
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2006  7.55  7.63  7.62  7.50  7.47  7.53  7.55  7.47  7.65  7.72  7.78  7.81
2007  7.71  7.67  7.85  7.82  7.91  7.91  8.00  7.82  7.90  7.93  7.99  7.93
2008  8.46  8.48  9.03  9.43 11.58 12.19 12.23 11.98 12.26 12.31 12.13 11.99
2009 11.51 11.75 11.87 11.91 11.87 11.69 11.66 11.23 11.37 11.71 11.88 11.93
2010 11.99 11.84 12.33 12.55 12.58 12.67 12.57 12.35 12.30 12.67 12.71 12.63
2011 12.60 12.41 12.68 12.48 12.50 12.30 12.39 12.16 12.38 12.36 12.52 12.63
```

I have referred to [Timeseries analysis procedure and methods using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140163/timeseries-analysis-procedure-and-methods-using-r?lq=1), to do a series of different model of forecasting, however it does not seems to be accurate. In additional, I am not sure how to incorporate the tsoutliers into it as well.

I have got another post regarding my enquiry of tsoutliers and arima modelling and procedure over [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168655/how-to-interpret-and-do-forecasting-using-tsoutliers-package-and-auto-arima/168869#168869) as well.

So these are my code currently, which is similar to link no.1.

**Code:**

```
product<-ts(product, start=c(1993,1),frequency=12)

#Modelling product Retail Price

#Training set
product.mod<-window(product,end=c(2012,12))
#Test set
product.test<-window(product,start=c(2013,1))
#Range of time of test set
period<-(end(product.test)[1]-start(product.test)[1])*12 + #No of month * no. of yr
(end(product.test)[2]-start(product.test)[2]+1) #No of months
#Model using different method
#arima, expo smooth, theta, random walk, structural time series
models<-list(
#arima
product.arima<-forecast(auto.arima(product.mod),h=period),
#exp smoothing
product.ets<-forecast(ets(product.mod),h=period),
#theta
product.tht<-thetaf(product.mod,h=period),
#random walk
product.rwf<-rwf(product.mod,h=period),
#Structts
product.struc<-forecast(StructTS(product.mod),h=period)
)

##Compare the training set forecast with test set
par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
for (f in models){
    plot(f)
    lines(product.test,col='red')
}

##To see its accuracy on its Test set, 
#as training set would be "accurate" in the first place
acc.test<-lapply(models, function(f){
    accuracy(f, product.test)[2,]
})
acc.test <- Reduce(rbind, acc.test)
row.names(acc.test)<-c("arima","expsmooth","theta","randomwalk","struc")
acc.test <- acc.test[order(acc.test[,'MASE']),]

##Look at training set to see if there are overfitting of the forecasting
##on training set
acc.train<-lapply(models, function(f){
    accuracy(f, product.test)[1,]
})
acc.train <- Reduce(rbind, acc.train)
row.names(acc.train)<-c("arima","expsmooth","theta","randomwalk","struc")
acc.train <- acc.train[order(acc.train[,'MASE']),]

 ##Note that we look at MAE, MAPE or MASE value. The lower the better the fit.
```

This is the plot of my different forecasting, which doesn't seem very reliable/accurate, through the comparison of the red"test set", and blue"forecasted" set.
**Plot of different forecast**
[image: Different forecast]

**Different accuracy of the respective models of test and training set**

```
Test set
                    ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
theta      -0.07408833 0.2277015 0.1881167 -0.6037191 1.460549 0.2944165 0.1956893 0.8322151
expsmooth  -0.12237967 0.2681452 0.2268248 -0.9823104 1.765287 0.3549976 0.3432275 0.9847223
randomwalk  0.11965517 0.2916008 0.2362069  0.8823040 1.807434 0.3696813 0.4529428 1.0626775
arima      -0.32556886 0.3943527 0.3255689 -2.5326397 2.532640 0.5095394 0.2076844 1.4452932
struc      -0.39735804 0.4573140 0.3973580 -3.0794740 3.079474 0.6218948 0.3841505 1.6767075

Training set
                     ME      RMSE       MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE    ACF1 Theil's U
theta      2.934494e-02 0.2101747 0.1046614  0.30793753 1.143115 0.1638029  0.2191889194        NA
randomwalk 2.953975e-02 0.2106058 0.1050209  0.31049479 1.146559 0.1643655  0.2190857676        NA
expsmooth  1.277048e-02 0.2037005 0.1078265  0.14375355 1.176651 0.1687565 -0.0007393747        NA
arima      4.001011e-05 0.2006623 0.1079862 -0.03405395 1.192417 0.1690063 -0.0091275716        NA
struc      5.011615e-03 1.0068396 0.5520857  0.18206018 5.989414 0.8640550  0.1499843508        NA
```

From the models accuracy, we can see that the most accurate model would be theta model.
I am not sure why is the forecast very inaccurate, and I think that one of the reasons would be that, I did not treat the "outliers" in my data set, resulting in a bad forecast for all model.

**This is my outliers plot**

**Outliers Plot**
[image: Outliers]

**tsoutliers output**

```
ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,1)[12]                    

Coefficients:
        sma1    LS46    LS51    LS61    TC133   LS181   AO183   AO184   LS185   TC186    TC193    TC200
      0.1700  0.4316  0.6166  0.5793  -0.5127  0.5422  0.5138  0.9264  3.0762  0.5688  -0.4775  -0.4386
s.e.  0.0768  0.1109  0.1105  0.1106   0.1021  0.1120  0.1119  0.1567  0.1918  0.1037   0.1033   0.1040
       LS207    AO237    TC248    AO260    AO266
      0.4228  -0.3815  -0.4082  -0.4830  -0.5183
s.e.  0.1129   0.0782   0.1030   0.0801   0.0805

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01258:  log likelihood=205.91
AIC=-375.83   AICc=-373.08   BIC=-311.19

 Outliers:
    type ind    time coefhat  tstat
1    LS  46 1996:10  0.4316  3.891
2    LS  51 1997:03  0.6166  5.579
3    LS  61 1998:01  0.5793  5.236
4    TC 133 2004:01 -0.5127 -5.019
5    LS 181 2008:01  0.5422  4.841 
6    AO 183 2008:03  0.5138  4.592
7    AO 184 2008:04  0.9264  5.911
8    LS 185 2008:05  3.0762 16.038
9    TC 186 2008:06  0.5688  5.483
10   TC 193 2009:01 -0.4775 -4.624
11   TC 200 2009:08 -0.4386 -4.217
12   LS 207 2010:03  0.4228  3.746
13   AO 237 2012:09 -0.3815 -4.877
14   TC 248 2013:08 -0.4082 -3.965
15   AO 260 2014:08 -0.4830 -6.027
16   AO 266 2015:02 -0.5183 -6.442
```

I would like to know how can I further "analyse"/forecast my data, with these relevant data set and detection of outliers, etc.
Please do help me in treatment of my outliers as well to do my forecasting as well .

Lastly, I would like to know how to combined the different model forecasting together, as from what @forecaster had mentioned in link no.1, combining the different model will most likely result in a better forecasting/prediction.

**EDITED**

I would like to incorporate the outliers in other models are well.

I have tried some codes, eg.

```
forecast.ets( res$fit ,h=period,xreg=newxreg)
Error in if (object$components[1] == "A" & is.element(object$components[2], : argument is of length zero

forecast.StructTS(res$fit,h=period,xreg=newxreg)
Error in predict.Arima(object, n.ahead = h) : 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns
```

There are some errors produced, and I am unsure about the correct code to incorporate the outliers as regressors.
Furthermore, how do I work with thetaf or rwf, as there are no forecast.theta or forecast.rwf?

Comment: Perhaps you should take another approach to getting help as continuous re-editing doesn't seem to work

Comment: I agree with @irishstat, both answers below provide direct answer to your question, and seem to have received little attention.

Comment: Try reading documentation of the specific functions which is giving you errors, ETS and thetaf does not have the capability to handle regressors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is also related to the points 6 and 7 of your [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168655/).

The outliers are understood as observations that are not explained by 
the model, so their role in the forecasts is limited in the sense that the presence of new outliers will not be predicted. All you need to do is to include these outliers in the forecast equation.

In the case of an additive outlier (which affects a single observation), 
the variable containing this outlier will be simply filled with zeros, since the outlier was detected for an observation in the sample; in the case of a level shift (a permanent change in the data), the variable will be filled with ones in order to keep the shift in the forecasts.

---

Next, I show how to obtain forecasts in R upon an ARIMA model with the outliers detected by 'tsoutliers'. The key is to the define properly the argument `newxreg` that is passed to `predict`.

(This is only to illustrate the answer to your question about how to treat outliers when forecasting, I don't address the issue whether the resulting model or forecasts are the best solution.)

```
require(tsoutliers)
x <- c(
  7.55,  7.63,  7.62,  7.50,  7.47,  7.53,  7.55,  7.47,  7.65,  7.72,  7.78,  7.81,
  7.71,  7.67,  7.85,  7.82,  7.91,  7.91,  8.00,  7.82,  7.90,  7.93,  7.99,  7.93,
  8.46,  8.48,  9.03,  9.43, 11.58, 12.19, 12.23, 11.98, 12.26, 12.31, 12.13, 11.99,
 11.51, 11.75, 11.87, 11.91, 11.87, 11.69, 11.66, 11.23, 11.37, 11.71, 11.88, 11.93,
 11.99, 11.84, 12.33, 12.55, 12.58, 12.67, 12.57, 12.35, 12.30, 12.67, 12.71, 12.63,
 12.60, 12.41, 12.68, 12.48, 12.50, 12.30, 12.39, 12.16, 12.38, 12.36, 12.52, 12.63)
x <- ts(x, frequency=12, start=c(2006,1))
res <- tso(x, types=c("AO","LS","TC"))

# define the variables containing the outliers for
# the observations outside the sample
npred <- 12 # number of periods ahead to forecast 
newxreg <- outliers.effects(res$outliers, length(x) + npred)
newxreg <- ts(newxreg[-seq_along(x),], start = c(2012, 1))

# obtain the forecasts
p <- predict(res$fit, n.ahead=npred, newxreg=newxreg)

# display forecasts
plot(cbind(x, p$pred), plot.type = "single", ylab = "", type = "n", ylim=c(7,13))
lines(x)
lines(p$pred, type = "l", col = "blue")
lines(p$pred + 1.96 * p$se, type = "l", col = "red", lty = 2)  
lines(p$pred - 1.96 * p$se, type = "l", col = "red", lty = 2)  
legend("topleft", legend = c("observed data", 
  "forecasts", "95% confidence bands"), lty = c(1,1,2,2), 
  col = c("black", "blue", "red", "red"), bty = "n")
```

[image: forecasts]

**Edit**

The function `predict` as used above returns forecasts based on the chosen ARIMA model, ARIMA(2,0,0) stored in `res$fit` and the detected outliers, `res$outliers`. We have a model equation like this:

$$
y_t = \sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j L_j(B) I_t(t_j) + \frac{\theta(B)}{\phi(B) \alpha(B)} \epsilon_t \,, \quad \epsilon_t \sim NID(0, \sigma^2) \,,
$$

where $L_j$ is the polynomial related to the $j$-th outlier (see the documentation of `tsoutliers` or the original paper by Chen and Liu cited in my answer to you other question); $I_t$ is an indicator variable; and the last term consist of the polynomials that define the ARMA model.

Comment: so what you did was to add outliers into the argument "newxreg". Is this called the regressor? Can I know the use of regressor? In additional, through the use of regressor in "predict" function, does it still use ARIMA? or it is different forecasting method? Thanks alot for your help in the use of tsoutliers. =D

Comment: is it possible to incorporate outliers as regressor to be used in forecasting in other models as well? like Basic Structural Model, Theta, Random Walk and etc?

Comment: @Ted Yes, the forecasts are based on an ARMA model. I have edited my answer with some details about this.

Comment: You can incorporate regressor variables containing effects like level shifts, additive outliers,... in other models as well, e.g., random walk, 
structural time series model,... If you are asking how to use some software to do that, you should probably ask it in another post and consider whether the question is better suited for other sites like [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: oh ok. Another question would be, do you know if there is a difference between using *predict* and *forecast*? If there is, what are the difference

Comment: For ARIMA models, there are no differences between `stats::predict` and `forecasts::forecast`. You can check it: `p2 <- forecast.Arima(res$fit, h=npred, xreg=newxreg)` `all.equal(p$pred, p2$mean)`. `forecasts::forecast` can be applied for other types of time series models or methods mentioned in the documentation (`ets`, `StructTS`,...) and the ARIMA model may include a drift term, which I think it is not handled by `predict`.

Comment: I have tried it on forecast.Arima, and it works! I would like to incorporate it with ets, StructTS, thetaf and rwf as well. But there are errors produced and there are not forecast.thetaf function as well. I have post the question on the Edited portion, can you help me with this? Thanks alot!!

Comment: @Ted, before using these techniques, I would check the documentation or try to read a book on forecasting especially [Forecasting Principles and Practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/) and determine why you have errors and also get basic understanding of these techniques. Both thetaf and ets do have the capability to handle regressors.

Comment: The model stored in `res$fit` is of class `Arima` and, hence, the forecasts will be based on an ARIMA model. You cannot get forecasts based on `ets` because the fitted model stored in `res$fit` is not of that class. As forecaster mentions, external regressors can be considered in ETS (and StructTS), but I don't know if this functionality is implemented in `forecast` in a simple way as it is for ARIMA models.

Comment: This is becoming a question more about software usage rather than statistics, you could consider post it as a separate question at 
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Using a piece of software that I have helped develop a reasonable model for your 72 observations would include a power transform (logs) as the error variance is linkable to the expected value. This is also fairly obvious from the original plot where the eye can detect increased variance at the higher level.[image] with actual.fit/forecast [image] and a plot of the final [image]residuals . Note the more realistic confidence limits taking into account the power transform . Although this response doesn't use R it does
raise the bar as to what a reasonable model using R might include.