# how can I make ARIMA more robust to outliers?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a very noisy time series like this and I forcast future values with `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package in R:

```
set.seed(123)
y <- diffinv(rnorm(100))

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(y))))
```

[image]

I am quite happy with this forecast. However, in my data, sometimes extreme outliers can happen, for example:

```
y[100] <- -10

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(y))))
```

These completely destroy my forecast. How can I make it so that ARIMA is robust to those outliers or would I have to detect and remove these outliers separetly?

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169468/how-to-do-forecasting-with-detection-of-outliers-in-r-time-series-analysis-pr/173684?s=2|28.2897#173684) and the [tsoutliers](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tsoutliers) package of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARIMA on its own can't really handle outliers. You need to use [tsclean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.4/topics/tsclean) or some other similar preprocessing method.